# Oracle SQL - dynamic case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to turn the below Oracle SQL query into a dynamic query? What I mean is, I have hard coded the values for the case statement as 'INTERNET', 'SALES' ETC... Is it possible to avoid hard coding? My source column is dynamic. I was thinking a for loop and array, but is that available in SQL? If someone could get me going on this, that would be great. Thank you.

```
SELECT
        NVL(status, 'Grand Total') AS "ROW LABELS",
        COUNT(case when source = 'INTERNET' THEN 1 end) AS "INTERNET",
        COUNT(case when source = 'SALES' THEN 1 end) AS "SALES",
        COUNT(case when source = 'DEMO' THEN 1 end) AS "DEMO",
        COUNT(case when source = 'COM' THEN 1 end) AS "COM",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN order_source IN ('INTERNET', 'SALES', 'DEMO', 'COM') THEN 1 END) AS "Grand Total"
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY ROLLUP(status);
```

Comment: How would you know which values to include in 'total'? Or are you including everything - if so that case is a bit pointless.

Comment: Yes, you can make this query dynamic.  I would build the query dynamically in what ever code language you are using, c#, php, etc.  If you can't do that, you can use a while loop or cursor in oracle.  Let us know more about your requirments and how you determine what values to go in your case statements.

Comment: maybe you are asking about a PIVOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a PIVOT function with dynamic columns definition. The simplest way is pivot xml:

```
create table tst_data (id int primary key, source varchar2(255));

insert into tst_data values (1, 'INTERNET');
insert into tst_data values (2, 'DEMO');
insert into tst_data values (3, 'INTERNET');
insert into tst_data values (4, 'SALES');
insert into tst_data values (5, 'INTERNET');
insert into tst_data values (6, 'DEMO');
insert into tst_data values (7, 'INTERNET');
insert into tst_data values (8, 'COM');

commit;

select * from (
  select source from tst_data
) 
pivot xml 
(
  count(1)
  for source in (select distinct t.source from tst_data t)
)
```

After you need to process XML data:

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name = "SOURCE">COM</column>
        <column name = "COUNT(1)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "SOURCE">DEMO</column>
        <column name = "COUNT(1)">2</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "SOURCE">INTERNET</column>
        <column name = "COUNT(1)">4</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "SOURCE">SALES</column>
        <column name = "COUNT(1)">1</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

`PIVOT XML` supports dynamic columns definition (`for source in (select distinct t.source from tst_data t)`) however it returns XML data. `Extractvalue` and `xmltable` functions allow to query particular columns from the XML on server side but you have to specify field names in advance. So I assume to parse it on client side.

If you want to do everything on DB-layer there is another approach. `PIVOT` (not XML) requires columns names `for source in ('INTERNET', 'DEMO', 'COM', ...)`. It's possible to generate such a query and return a *cursor* to client side:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCTION1 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS 
 cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open cur for 'select * from dual'; // generate PIVOT query here
  RETURN cur;
END FUNCTION1;
```

I don't know any method to create a simple untyped query from the cursor (on server side), so if you desire to use a plain SQL query do it in two steps:

1. Generate a PIVOT query with named columns in PL/SQL function;
2. Run the query from your client.

Comment: Hey how would I process the XML data?

Comment: @NomanArain where do you need it? I mean can you do it on client side or server side?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do it in plain SQL. You could make a function that generates the results dynamically; maybe easier to handle than with an anonymous block:

```
create or replace function get_counts return sys_refcursor as
  query varchar2(32767);
  rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  query := 'select nvl(status, ''Grand Total'') as row_labels';
  for tmp in (select distinct source from sometable order by 1)
  loop
    query := query || ', count(case when source = ''' || tmp.source
      || ''' then 1 end) as "' || substr(tmp.source, 1, 30) || '"';
  end loop;
  query := query || ', count(*) as total';
  query := query || ' from sometable';
  query := query || ' group by rollup(status)';
  query := query || ' order by status';

  open rc for query;

  return rc;
end;
/
```

To run in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (with 'run as a script'):

```
var rc refcursor;
exec :rc := get_counts;
print rc
```

You can also do this as a query:

```
select get_counts from dual;
```

In SQL Developer that shows an unhelpful-looking display in the query output window, but if you double-click the value (which looks something like `{<ROW_LABELS=...>}`) then an edit icon appears at the far right; click that and the actual values will be shown in a new window.

I'm assuming 'total' should include everything; if not I'm not sure how you'd determine what to include dynamically. If you can do that though you could keep a separate variable or collection that builds the case statement for the total as you loop through, then add it afterwards.