# convert sql table in matrix form

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle and I want to convert it in matrix form

table 1 : I have two type of users with corresponding weights

```
  User_name  M_User    Total
    user 1    user 2     7
    user 1    user 3     19
    user 1    user 7     5
    user 3    user 2     1
    user 2    user 7     1
```

The final result should be something like this: user 1 - > user two has weight 7 so this value appears in that cell and so on

```
             user 1 user 2 user 3  user 7
user 1        0        7     19       5
user 3        0        1      0       0
user 2        0        0      0       1
user 7        0        0      0       0
```

After a bit of research I found Pivot function and used it.

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT USER_NAME, M_USER, TOTAL
        FROM   TEST)
PIVOT  (MAX(TOTAL)  FOR (M_USER) IN ('user 2' AS User2, 'user 3' AS User3 , 'user7' AS User7))
```

First problem is that it is showing null values for 'User 7' and it shouldn't, second problem is that I have lot of data in my file (107k records,including duplicates) for limited data like above I can use  `'user 2' AS User2, 'user 3' AS User3 , 'user7' AS User7` after `IN` command in case of such big data how can i write this line? of course I can't write 100k records after `IN`

UPDATE:
ran the commands in sql developer as "run script"

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
EXEC :rc := getusers;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.GETUSERS is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
rc
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful for you. I have used `CASE WHEN THEN END` blocks to achieve the `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT USERS.USER_NAME
  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.USER1, 0)) USER1
  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.USER2, 0)) USER2
  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.USER3, 0)) USER3
  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.USER7, 0)) USER7
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME 
  FROM (
      SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST
      UNION ALL
      SELECT M_USER FROM TEST
    )
  ) USERS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
          USER_NAME
          , M_USER
          , CASE WHEN M_USER = 'user 1' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS USER1
          , CASE WHEN M_USER = 'user 2' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS USER2
          , CASE WHEN M_USER = 'user 3' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS USER3
          , CASE WHEN M_USER = 'user 7' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS USER7
      FROM TEST
    ) TEST ON USERS.USER_NAME = TEST.USER_NAME
GROUP BY USERS.USER_NAME
ORDER BY USERS.USER_NAME
```

**UPDATE**

I could not find a way write this in a single query. After some analysis i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808808/oracle-sql-dynamic-case-statement).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETUSERS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
  QUERY VARCHAR2(32767);
  RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  QUERY := 'SELECT USERS.USER_NAME ';

  FOR TMP IN (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(REPLACE(USER_NAME, ' ', '')) USER_NAME FROM (SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST UNION ALL SELECT M_USER FROM TEST) ORDER BY USER_NAME)
  LOOP
    QUERY := QUERY || '  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.' || TMP.USER_NAME || ' , 0)) ' || TMP.USER_NAME;
  END LOOP;

  QUERY := QUERY || ' FROM ( ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  FROM ( ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '      SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '      UNION ALL ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '      SELECT M_USER FROM TEST ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '    ) ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  ) USERS ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( ';

  QUERY := QUERY || ' SELECT USER_NAME';
  FOR TMP IN (SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME, REPLACE(USER_NAME, ' ', '') USER_COL_NM FROM (SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST UNION ALL SELECT M_USER FROM TEST))
  LOOP
    QUERY := QUERY || ', CASE WHEN M_USER = ''' || TMP.USER_NAME
      || ''' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS ' || TMP.USER_COL_NM ;
  END LOOP;
  QUERY := QUERY || ' FROM TEST';

  QUERY := QUERY || '    ) TEST ON USERS.USER_NAME = TEST.USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || 'GROUP BY USERS.USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || 'ORDER BY USERS.USER_NAME';

  OPEN RC FOR QUERY;

  RETURN RC;
END;
/
```

Created function which dynamically creates the `SQL` and returns `SYS_REFCURSOR`. This can be run in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (with 'run as a script'),

```
VAR RC REFCURSOR;
EXEC :RC := GETUSERS;
PRINT RC
```

Comment: This is better than using pivot thanks for that , but what about the generic case? as I have stated above that this is just a sample data my original data has almost 1 lac 7k records

Comment: yeah. i did not completely read your post. Sorry. This is not good for generic case. Let me think about it.

Comment: @melissa i have made some updates. Lot of information are gathered from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808808/oracle-sql-dynamic-case-statement

Comment: the above sql query runs successfully but I can't see the output as the later commands are giving me error (which I have added above in my main post under update) also can I save it in table form? as I need to extract this data later in excel sheet