# PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small (buffer size unlimited)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle and I want to convert it in matrix form

table 1 : I have two type of users with corresponding weights

```
  User_name  M_User    Total
    user 1    user 2     7
    user 1    user 3     19
    user 1    user 7     5
    user 3    user 2     1
    user 2    user 7     1
```

The final result should be something like this: user 1 - > user two has weight 7 so this value appears in that cell and so on

```
            user 1 user 2 user 3  user 7
user 1        0        7     19       5
user 3        0        1      0       0
user 2        0        0      0       1
user 7        0        0      0       0
```

I tried the pivot function but

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT USER_NAME, M_USER, TOTAL
        FROM   TEST)
PIVOT  (MAX(TOTAL)  FOR (M_USER) IN ('user 2' AS User2, 'user 3' AS User3 , 'user7' AS User7))
```

First problem is that it is showing null values for 'User 7' and it shouldn't, second problem is that I have lot of data in my file (107k records,including duplicates) for limited data like above I can use 'user 2' AS User2, 'user 3' AS User3 , 'user7' AS User7 after IN command in case of such big data how can i write this line? of course I can't write 100k records after IN

I'm running a script on data of 107k records and I'm getting the above mentioned error, the code works for small dataset but not for my original dataset

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETUSERS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
  QUERY CLOB;
  RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  QUERY := 'SELECT USERS.USER_NAME ';

  FOR TMP IN (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(REPLACE(USER_NAME, ' ', '')) USER_NAME FROM (SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST UNION ALL SELECT M_USER FROM TEST) ORDER BY USER_NAME)
  LOOP
  QUERY := QUERY || '  , MAX(COALESCE(TEST.' || TMP.USER_NAME || ' , 0)) ' || TMP.USER_NAME;
  END LOOP;

  QUERY := QUERY || ' FROM ( ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  FROM ( ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  UNION ALL ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  SELECT M_USER FROM TEST ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  ) ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  ) USERS ';
  QUERY := QUERY || '  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( ';

  QUERY := QUERY || ' SELECT USER_NAME';
  FOR TMP IN (SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME, REPLACE(USER_NAME, ' ', '') USER_COL_NM FROM (SELECT USER_NAME FROM TEST UNION ALL SELECT M_USER FROM TEST))
  LOOP
  QUERY := QUERY || ', CASE WHEN M_USER = ''' || TMP.USER_NAME
  || ''' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END AS ' || TMP.USER_COL_NM ;
  END LOOP;
  QUERY := QUERY || ' FROM TEST';

  QUERY := QUERY || '  ) TEST ON USERS.USER_NAME = TEST.USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || 'GROUP BY USERS.USER_NAME ';
  QUERY := QUERY || 'ORDER BY USERS.USER_NAME';

  OPEN RC FOR QUERY;

  RETURN RC;
END;
/
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
EXEC :RC := GETUSERS;
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "GETUSERS", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
RC
------
```

I have read other questions similar to this and all of them recommended setting `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(500000);` I tried but it gave me the unknown command error so I manually set the buffer size to unlimited in `DBMS OUTPUT` but I'm still getting the error, any help?

[Here is a link to my earlier question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033697/convert-sql-table-in-matrix-form)

Comment: When I am have created large dynamic queries in Oracle, I have used the `CLOB` data type.

Comment: I don't know how many users you have, but you `LOOP` through all users and append data to `QUERY` again and again in that loop (Lines 5-7). I guess your query simply gets longer than allowed

Comment: @Abihabi87 That is the limit in the SQL scope - in the [PL/SQL scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS311) a `VARCHAR2` can have 32,767 bytes

Comment: @GordonLinoff clob works ok with small data but when I apply it on original data it gives me 'missing right parenthesis' error. weird!

Comment: @Psi around 10k distinct users

Comment: So you're going to generate a report that's ten thousand columns wide?

Comment: So you have a variable called `QUERY` which is at maximum 32,767 characters long. You have ~10,000 users and try to add text to your query in a `FOR-LOOP` 10,000 times. I hope you can do the maths on your own: more than ~3.27 characters per user and your query variable runs out of space.

Comment: @Melissa, can I propose a different question to you. What are you trying to accomplish? This seems rather extreme? Like Psi mentioned this would easily blow the limit on the variable (simple math). However, if you explain what your goal is, perhaps we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: @Miguel sure I will update the above question

Comment: @Psi I know it's a dumb approach and I totally overlooked the simple maths argh

Comment: I tried CLOB instead of varchar and it's giving me missing parenthesis error